# How to delay a job in a CI/CD gitlab pipeline until a certain time?

Tags: gitlab, cicd

With `start_in: 30 minutes` it's possible to delay a job (eg live deployment after a commit).

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#run-a-job-after-a-delay

Question: is it possible to also create a delay until a specific time?

Eg that the deployment is delayed until 5a.m.?
Something like `start_at: 05:00`?

Answer (score 2):

You could approximate this with a [dynamic child pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/parent_child_pipelines.html#dynamic-child-pipeline-example). The job that generates the configuration can calculate how much time is inbetween the current time and the desired deploy time and embed that in the generated config for the `start_in` parameter.

As an example:

```yaml
create_deploy_pipeline:
  stage: build
  script:
  # modify this line or write a script that suits your needs
  # here, we calculate the number of seconds between now and "5AM tomorrow"
  - seconds_until_deploy=$(( $(date +%s -d "tomorrow 05:00") - $( date +%s ) ))
  - |
    cat > dynamic.yml << EOF
    deploy_job:
      script:
        - ./deploy.sh
      when: delayed
      start_in: ${seconds_until_deploy} seconds
    EOF
artifacts:
    paths:
      - dynamic.yml


deploy-pipeline:
  stage: test
  trigger:
    include:
      - artifact: dynamic.yml
        job: create_deploy_pipeline
```

Keep in mind that you will need to consider the timezone used by your runner (or calculate using UTC time) to get an accurate calculation.

Comment: That's a great idea! However, what if there are several commits during the day. Each commit will then schedule the deployment pipeline again. Could I restrict that job only to the latest known active pipeline?

Comment: @membersound hmm. If you add the `environment:` key to the deployment job, the default behavior for GitLab is to [skip outdated deployment jobs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/deployment_safety.html#skip-outdated-deployment-jobs) ensuring that older pipelines never deploy over the latest jobs. Maybe that will work for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

What you are probably looking for is a [scheduled pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/schedules.html#scheduled-pipelines). Scheduled pipelines benefit from execution based on cron clauses. You can limit the execution of your complete pipeline definition on a step by step basis like [this](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#run-jobs-for-scheduled-pipelines).

**EDIT:** Avoiding duplicate pipeline runs has been documented [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#avoid-duplicate-pipelines). If you tag your deployments you could build a command like this:

```
git log --oneline $(git describe --tags --abbrev=0 @^)..@
```

This will tell you if there are any commits since the last tag. This could be a Job Control feature to figure out, whether to run again or not.

Comment: But how can I tell the schedule that it should only run (each night) if there has been a new commit between the latest run?

Comment: I have added an update to my answer although I am not sure if your problem can be solved via GitLab CI natively.